# "ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script" when I am running the script with Java 1.8

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan I have the following script,

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def completeFetchedStudyNameFromResponse = []; 
1. upto(vars.get('studyNameFetched_matchNr') as int, {
  index ->
  completeFetchedStudyNameFromResponse.add(vars.get('studyNameFetched_' + index));
});

String tempToBeExcludedStudyName = vars.get('excludeStudyName');

def toBeDeleteStudy = [];
def studyNameNeedToExcludeFromDeletion = new JsonSlurper().parseText(tempToBeExcludedStudyName);

def filteredStudyName = completeFetchedStudyNameFromResponse.findAll {
  studyName ->
    studyNameNeedToExcludeFromDeletion.every {
      keywords ->
       studyName.contains(keywords)
    }
}
def bdConverter = new JsonSlurper();
def responseBDTemp = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
def responseBD = bdConverter.parseText(responseBDTemp);
def resultStudyUUIDCollector = [];
def parsedResultBD = responseBD.accounts;


filteredStudyName.each { studyNameFew ->
  resultStudyUUIDCollector.add(responseBD.accounts.find { account -> account.name == studyNameFew }.uuid)  
}

vars.putObject("myList", resultStudyUUIDCollector);
```

This script works fine with JMeter 5.5 with Java 17 but when I run the same with JMeter 5.4 with Java 1.8, getting following error,

```
2023-06-16 11:34:58,180 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, StudyName_Processer
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class groovy.json.JsonSlurper
```

Is there anyway I can run the same with lower version of Java without upgrading ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the same with lower version of Java without downgrading the same because the same code should work fine for the same.

The error you're getting means that your JMeter 5.4 installation is broken because someone either being not very smart or by accident removed groovy-json-3.0.5.jar from "lib" folder of your JMeter

[image]

So either download [groovy-json-3.0.5.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-json/3.0.5) and drop it to "lib" folder of your JMeter 5.4 installation or [reinstall JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) completely as who knows what else is missing.

Also be informed that according to JMeter Best Practices [you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as it contains bug fixes, new features and performance improvements. In particular JMeter 5.4 suffers from [Log4Shell](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2021-44228) so it makes sense to consider upgrading the same to JMeter 5.5 so your JMeter versions would be the same.